# Is it possible to have server(_name) map to a subfolder in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I already have a configuration for application that covers my domain /, but I would like to have www.mydomain.com/something/thisthing to be covered by different config file, a different application altogether.

Is this possible in nginx and how?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use a separate config file for a specific location block, is that correct? If so, you can use the nginx directive include to include an outside configuration file. For example:

location /thisthing
{ include outside file; }

Once in that location block, you can handle that traffic however you see fit.

Comment: Indeed, but I want to have another root for that location as well. I tried root and alias directives in my location to no avail. I'm not sure, maybe root in server directive scope somehow overrides location scope.